# Лемматизация данных по столбцу с добавлением категориальных значений в отдельный столбец

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Есть dataframe в pandas с импортированной таблицей, в которой есть определенный столбец категориальных переменных введенных руками. Не могу понять, как из этого списка, через лемматизацию и добавления столбца в ДФ сделать еще один столбец с категориальными переменными прошедшими через лемматизацию?
Например изначальный столбец

```
df['out']
[около музей лицо]
[лицей кинотеатр]
[машина кино лица окно улица]
```

Нужно получить столбец df['zero'] в котором в столбик, по одному слову в ячейке будет перечислены слова из столбца 'out' прошедшие лемматизацию, т.е. столбец должен выглядеть:

```
[лица]
[кино]
[кино]
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Уточнил, поправил первоначальную задачу

Comment: непонятно почему выбраны именно эти слова...

Comment: кинотеатр - лемма "кино"?